# thread C# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

у меня есть форма, на ней проигрывается видео, и есть check box нажимая на который с видео должны начать сохраняться кадры в виде фото. Проблема в том что в потоке используется this, и оно ругается,нельзя передавать в другой поток элемент формы, как исправить эту ошибку? вот поток и в нём код который сохраняет изображение.

```
private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checking == 1)
        {
            cancel = false;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (cancel==false)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WMP.URL))
                    {
                        //WMP.Ctlcontrols.pause();

                        System.Drawing.Image ret = null;
                        try
                        {

                            // take picture BEFORE saveFileDialog pops up!!
                            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(970, 500);
                            {
                                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                                {
                                    Graphics gg = WMP.CreateGraphics();
                                    {
                                        //timerTakePicFromVideo.Start();
                                        this.BringToFront();
                                        g.CopyFromScreen(
                                             WMP.PointToScreen(
                                                new System.Drawing.Point()).X,
                                             WMP.PointToScreen(
                                                new System.Drawing.Point()).Y,
                                            -70, -40,
                                            new System.Drawing.Size(
                                                  2349, 551)
                                            );
                                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                                    }
                                }
                                // afterwards save bitmap file if user wants to

                                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                                    ret = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                                    ret.Save(folder + "/img" + number + ".jpg");
                                    number += 1;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("error: "+ ex);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            );
            checking = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cancel = true;
            checking = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А надо просто запускать таску, дисейблить эту кнопку которой это обработчик и выходить из обработчика события, тогда `GUI` будет нормально работать. А в конце таски обратно энейблить кнопку. Вам же не нужно, чтобы кнопку второй раз могли нажать, пока цикл записи не закончен? Только таску лучше сохранять во внешнюю переменную, чтобы её `GC` случайно не мог утилизировать (хотя тут я не уверен).

Comment: @CrazyElf GC не утилизирует рабочие таски, связанные с потоками до тех пор, пока поток не будет завершен. С другой стороны, ликвидация таска, на который нет ссылок, погоды вообще не сделает, поток при этом не завершится.

Comment: "ругается на строчку this.BringToFront(); пишет Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'Form1' не из того потока, в котором он был создан" - отрисовка элементов должна быть в основном потоке, а у вас поток таска отдельный. Я не помню как это в тасках решается, раньше через `Invoke` как-то делалось что ли.

Comment: Я перестал понимать вопрос, оформите его нормально, объясните, что вообще происходит. Какой-то код, что-то делает, работает, не работает - непонятно. Ошибка возникает? Какая? Покажите текст ошибки.

Comment: @aepot Новую ошибку он в комментарии к удалённому ответу написал, я её скопировал тут в комментарий.

Comment: Вангую: `Invoke((Action)(() => BringToFront()));`

Comment: Вообще не совсем понятно, что это за набор костылей. Если нужно покадрово видео сохранять, значит надо брать кадры из проигрывателя. А так вы только нагрузите на 100% проц/диск и получите, либо кучу повторяющихся кадров, либо кучу пропущенных.

Comment: Да, решил с помошью invoke, cпасибо за помошь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением был ответ в коментариях, продублирую его сюда что бы было видно.

```
Invoke((Action)(() => BringToFront()));
```